# How to use text as criteria on micorosft excel

Tags: excel

I have a problem with my search text formula.
Here is my data in A2 and A3:

```
A2=>  Apple;P1;P2
A3=>  App;P1;P2
```

I want to match cells that contain text `"App"`.
Formula I used:

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND("App";A2))
```

but it returns `TRUE` for both `Apple` and `App`. It should be `TRUE` only cells than contain `"App"`.

Comment: `Apple` contains `App`, doesn't it? If your text is always before the first `;` you can be looking for `App;` but even then it will find `BadApp;P1;P2`.

Comment: The data sometimes on the middle. sometimes only one text. like following example : P1;App;P2 or only single data that is "App" only

Comment: The other data have this.."WW1,WW10,WW100" how can i find for only WW1?

Answer (score 0):

Look for "App;" will be most simple.,

The other option will be to split this cell and look for "app" in results.

Comment: Need to add the delimiter to the end of the string being searched in case searchstring occurs at the end.

Comment: including semicolon or comma within the search, get me into problem when i need to find "App1;" on range data App1;App2;App3;App4;App5;App6;App7;App8;App9;App10;

Comment: @user3357429 Why?  If your string is in A2, then simply:  `=ISNUMBER(FIND("App1;",A2&";"))`

Comment: Hi Ron Rosenfeld, your answer solved my problem. Add &";" after A2. thankyou for All

Comment: @user3357429 Then add it before `A2` as well and always look for `;App1;`, otherwise it will find `App;` in `BadApp;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to engage in writing a VBA function to split the values at the `;`, you can probably get away with the lazy version:

```
=OR(LEFT(A1,LEN("App;"))="App;",ISNUMBER(FIND(";App;",A1)),RIGHT(A1,LEN(";App"))=";App")
```